# Apprtc With PushNotificaiton

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apprtcdemo, apprtc

Consider I logged in as "Alice" In List View I'm showing list of users,If i click on any user I'm initiating video call,user which i selected(eg I selected "BOB") has to get Push notification,Once BOB Clicks on that notification Call has to connect between both.

**My Question is  :**
  From which Class I have to write code for push notification

** I'm using this github code https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is thread related issue. You should connect the aprtc video call when you are getting response of push notification api or call api to send the push is in background thread.